# EF problems when overide OnModelCreating Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to asp.net, I'm following this blog to extending and modifying Roles in asp.net mvc EF6.0 Identity version 2.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/727054/ASP-NET-MVC-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-R

Here's the problem

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        }

        // Keep this:
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        // Change TUser to ApplicationUser everywhere else - 
        // IdentityUser and ApplicationUser essentially 'share' the AspNetUsers Table in the database:
        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> table =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        table.Property((ApplicationUser u) => u.UserName).IsRequired();

        // EF won't let us swap out IdentityUserRole for ApplicationUserRole here:
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<IdentityUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey((IdentityUserRole r) =>
            new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        //Leave this alone:
        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin> entityTypeConfiguration =
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey((IdentityUserLogin l) =>
                new
                {
                    UserId = l.UserId,
                    LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider,
                    ProviderKey
                        = l.ProviderKey
                }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

        entityTypeConfiguration.HasRequired<IdentityUser>((IdentityUserLogin u) => u.);

        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim> table1 =
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

        //table1.HasRequired<IdentityUser>((IdentityUserClaim u) => u.User);

        // Add this, so that IdentityRole can share a table with ApplicationRole:
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        // Change these from IdentityRole to ApplicationRole:
        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((ApplicationRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();
    }
```

The Problem is in this line of code

```
entityTypeConfiguration.HasRequired<IdentityUser>((IdentityUserLogin u) => u.User);
```

Error output :

> Error 1   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin'
>   does not contain a definition for 'User' and no extension method
>   'User' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find something? I got the same error!